# Grouping by Date from DateTime in Postgre SQL

Tags: postgresql

So my table consists of a column of the type: timestamp with timezone.

For example, 
This is an entry from the column: 
2016-07-01 07:01:03+00

I would like to be able to group using just "2016-07-01" in my grouping-aggregation query.

How can I extract the date from the timestamp column and group using just that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `... group by date_column_name::date`

Comment: That works, but beware the date is in UTC. Also, see [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/006b01c4fecd%246d37c9e0%240b00a8c0%40forge) for info on creating a functional index to speed up queries by date. Might help with grouping, I'm not sure.